# Download file with today's date in its name from remote server with WinSCP

Tags: command-line, scripting, download, winscp

I want to use .bat and .txt files to download a daily file I have off of a remote directory

The root of the file is always the same, but the date changes...daily

```
get filename_yyyymmdd.txt
```

How can I search and download the file with today's date?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can rely on file timestamp, use [file mask with time-constaint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time).

See [WinSCP time based file download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16448038/850848).

---

If you have to rely on a file name, use the [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

```
get filename_%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%.txt
```

---

Also consider using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), instead of scripting. Particularly, if you know, say, PowerShell.