# WinSCP time based file download

Tags: command-line, download, scripting, timestamp, winscp

I would like to write WinSCP script to download a file that is placed onto the remote server every morning between 4-4:30am. Is there a way to do this with time-stamping?

I want to pseudocode:

```
get file.txt where timestap<1 hour from 4 am
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I assume your file does not have fixed name (contrary to your question with fixed name `file.txt`). If not, please explain, why do you need timestamp-based solution.

---

Anyway, you can use a [file mask with a time constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time):

```
get "*.txt>2014-07-19 4:00"
```

To dynamically inject today's date, use the [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

```
get "*.txt>%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-ss% 4:00"
```

Simply, the above means, get all files created later than 4:00 today (the `%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-ss%` resolves to today's date in format `yyyy-mm-ss`, as needed for the time constraint).

When passing the `get` on WinSCP command-line in a batch file (using `/command` switch, as opposite to using `/script` switch to specify a separate script file), you have to [double the `%`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file#percent) to avoid the batch-file trying to interpret the `%TIMESTAMP%`:

```
winscp.com /command ... "get ""*.txt>%%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-ss%% 4:00"""
```

---

Another solution is a static script that rely on a relative time: E.g. you know your script runs at 6am. So you let WinSCP download all files updated/created in the last 2 hours (6am – 4am):

```
get *.txt>2h
```

---

See also WinSCP article on [downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).