# Synchronizing today's files from remote to local directory using WinSCP

Tags: synchronization, winscp

I need to synchronize files from remote to local directory using the following command

```
synchronize local "D:\ftp\OUT" /out
```

It works fine but is there a way to download files which their dates of creation are today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [file mask with a time constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time) and `today` keyword:

```
synchronize local -filemask=">=today" "D:\ftp\OUT" /out
```

*This syntax is supported by WinSCP 5.15 and newer only.*

---

In earlier versions of WinSCP, you can use the [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp) to create the today's constraint.

```
synchronize local -filemask=">=%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%" "D:\ftp\OUT" /out
```

---

Further reading:

- Question [WinSCP time based file download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16448038/850848);
- WinSCP article on [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).