# Download files with specific date from SFTP server using PSFTP

Tags: sftp, putty

How can I download files of a specific time period through PSFTP?

When I do `mget *.*`, it downloads all the files into local folder. Now I’m not allowed to delete these files from SFTP server or move them. So every time I download, it has to download the complete list.

Is there a way where I can download only those files through `mget` which are a week old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSFTP does not support time-based file selection.

You can use scripting interface of WinSCP instead.
It supports [time-constraints in file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time).

To download all week old (7 days old) files, use the following command:

```
get *<7D
```

See the guide for [converting PSFTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp).

For general introduction to WinSCP scripting see:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

See also similar question [WinSCP time based file download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16448038/850848).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*