# Downloading files with today's date only from SFTP server with WinSCP

Tags: scripting, sftp, winscp

I am trying to only download files that are created today, just like tomorrow I would only want to download files created tomorrow only. Essentially I log into the remote server with my script and download all the files right now with `synchronize local`. What I want to do is just only download the files created today. Right now I just added the filemask and I am still getting all of the files however I only want today's files.

```
open sftp://location.net -passphrase="passphrase" -hostkey="key"
synchronize local C:\Users\localdrive\Desktop\test2   /Home/remoteFolder/
exit
```

I also tried

```
get /Home/remoteFolder/ -filemask=*>1D
```

and it hasn't changed anything.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [file mask with a time constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time) and the [`today` keyword](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#today) to create the today's constraint.

```
get -filemask=">=today" /remote/path/* C:\local\path\
```

*(You need WinSCP 5.15 or newer for the `today` keyword)*

---

*Your `*>1D` file mask downloads files created/modified in the last 24 hours, so not only today's files.*

Further reading:

- Question [WinSCP time based file download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16448038/850848),
- WinSCP article on [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

Comment: This is great. I was exactly looking for this. @Martin Prikryl .. you are such a great man!. Thanks